# how to convert quantitative variables into binary variables?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, odds-ratio, case-control-study

My problem is in finding the cut-off point which divide my continuous data into 2 binary outcome. I read articles they used  the 75th percentile of the control distribution as cut off point and they considered the controls below the 75th percentile as a reference group. the question is when i use this method, the controls who are above the 75th percentile will be excluded??is there any other advice regarding the best choice?

Comment: Why would you ever want to divide continuous data into a binary outcome? That is a really bad idea.

Comment: @gung what can i do instead? i want to conduct a logistic regression.

Comment: Use regular regression for continuous variables instead of logistic regression.